# Find one record with two conditions instead of one in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

There are three tables A,B and C, as follows:

```
A: id ip  
B: id cid sip dip   
C: id
```

In `A.java`,I want to get set <C>, with A's ip smaller than B's dip and bigger than B's sip,and B's id is joint to C's id. Just like follows:

```
@JoinTable(name="A", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name ="sip", referencedColumnName = "ip"),@JoinColumn(name ="dip", referencedColumnName = "ip")},
    inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name ="cid")})
    @WhereJoinTable(clause="ip::inet between sip::inet and dip::inet")
```

But it didn't work. Has anyone happened to come up against this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `JoinColumsOrFormulas`. I'm not sure how your table structure is, and what exactly you are trying to join, but below is a working example of a join that joins on the (primaryKey) `@JoinColumn` - sku and the ids that match the query in the `@JoinFormula`

```
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumnsOrFormulas({
            @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula(value = "(select a.id from uk_products a where a.asin != '' and a.product_name != '' and a.seller_sku = sku)", referencedColumnName = "id")),
            @JoinColumnOrFormula(column = @JoinColumn(name = "sku", referencedColumnName = "seller_sku", insertable = false, updatable = false))
    })
    @JoinColumn(name = "sku", referencedColumnName = "seller_sku", insertable = false, updatable = false)
```